# fgets that would skip when called the second time

Tags: c, fgets

I think the problem of my code is with my fgets but I do not know how to fix it. So, when I call the function for the first time, everything works, but if for the second time, the function skips everything after the printf.

So the output would be:

```
Output:
Please enter x and y coordinates separated by a comma for the piece you wish to enter: 3,4
x: 3, y:4
Please enter x and y coordinates separated by a comma for the piece you wish to enter: x:
, y:
```

This is the code:

```
void functioncall()
{
    char coord[4];
    printf("Please enter x and y coordinates separated by a comma for the piece you wish to place: ");
    fgets(coord, 4, stdin);

    char *xcoord = strtok(coord, ",");
    char *ycoord = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (!ycoord)
    {
        ycoord = "";
    }

    printf("x: %s, y: %s\n", xcoord, ycoord);
}
```

I cannot give an input when it is called for the second time.

Comment: Your string is way too small and can't fit the newline in, so the next `fgets()` gets just the newline.  Change 4 to 4096!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried to put a larger number before but it doest work

Comment: In what way didn't it work?  You should also check that `fgets()` returns a non-null pointer, because that's how it reports EOF.  Note that if someone enters `23,45` you have problems; or `-1,+1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The output is the same

Comment: Did you change both occurrences of 4 to 4096?  Or, better, change the second to `sizeof(coord)` so that no matter what you change the size of `coord` to, the call to `fgets()` is correct?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Havent thought using sizeof(coord), I'll give that a try

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yea it works, thanks

Comment: Where are you calling the function again?

Comment: @Dark Innocence This code I put up is just an example from my actual code, in the actual code i'm calling it to a game loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour you see is the size of the `coord` array.  When you specify the size as `4`, it means you can get 1 digit, 1 comma, 1 digit, and 1 null byte stored — which doesn't leave room for the newline, so the second call to the function reads the newline (only), which doesn't parse well.

You should allow for much more space — users are endlessly inventive in what they type (leading blanks, trailing blanks, intermediate blanks, signs, leading zeros, etc.).  I tend to use 4096 for single lines of input — partly for the shock value, and also because if someone's willing to write a 4-page essay on a single line, they deserve what they get.

This code works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void functioncall(void)
{
    char coord[4096];
    printf("Please enter x and y coordinates separated by a comma for the piece you wish to place: ");
    if (fgets(coord, sizeof(coord), stdin) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Got EOF in %s\n", __func__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    const char delims[] = ", \n\t";

    char *xcoord = strtok(coord, delims);
    char *ycoord = strtok(NULL, delims);
    if (!ycoord)
    {
        ycoord = "";
    }

    printf("x: [%s] y: [%s]\n", xcoord, ycoord);
}

int main(void)
{
    functioncall();
    functioncall();
    return 0;
}
```

Example run (program name `cd19`, source file `cd19.c`):

```
$ ./cd19
Please enter x and y coordinates separated by a comma for the piece you wish to place: 234 , 495
x: [234] y: [495]
Please enter x and y coordinates separated by a comma for the piece you wish to place: 1,2
x: [1] y: [2]
$
```

The choice of delimiter characters ensures that the `234 , 495` example works OK (the tab is optional, but not necessarily a bad idea).  It does, however, mean that the user is not obliged to enter a comma.